# scan4.coverity.com - Connection failed

Tags: coverity

I'm trying to do Static Analysis using Coverity Scan.
When "View defects" is executed, the following message will be displayed.
How can I resolve to view defects?

> scan4.coverity.com - Connection failed
>
> Error code 8
>
> The proxy failed to connect to the web server, due to TCP connection rejection (TCP Reset).

Comment: This problem was resolved at Oct 22, 2018.Probably, it is cause by network trouble.

Comment: It looks like it is back